# Our application cannot access anymore to customersdata through Google apps Marketplace

Tags: console, oauth-2.0, google-apps-marketplace

Our Marketplace application ID is 691703567391.

https://www.google.com/enterprise/marketplace/viewListing?productListingId=3198+1842896415262219465

Since 4-5 days, the application cannot access any customer data from the marketplace by using provisionning API and group provisionning APIs.
(apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/group/#readonly and apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/user/#readonly)

Whatever request our application is making, the response is always :

Error
401(Client Error)!!1
401.
That's an error.
There was an error in your request.
That's all we know.

For instance we did the GET request on the following URL : https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?xoauth_requestor_id=stef@gappsexperts.com and reponse was error 401.

After checking in cloud.google.com console, it appears that the Oauth1 reigtsred app has completely disappeared from our Cloud console (see screenshot)

Now only the Oauth2 app is available. I AM SURE THIS IS THE CAUSE OF THE PROBLEM.

Now here are the abnormal behaviours :

1/ We are getting errors for any request we make on user or group provisionning
2/ Oauth 1 registered app is not in the cloud.google.com console anymorre for this listing.
3/ WE CANNOT UNPUBLISH the listing in Google Apps Marketplace.

help us !

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you tried to create an OAuth 2 client ID in the same Developer Console project as your original Apps Marketplace developer console project?

I believe that might be a cause of this issue.

Your screenshot didn't come through in the post.